# When can reference arguments accept int literals?

Tags: c++

I'm watching a tutorial where Kate Gregory creates the function:

```
template <class T>
T max(T& t1, T& t2)
{
  return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}
```

and has the following code in main():

```
cout << "max of 33 and 44 is: " << max(33,44) << endl;
```

She compiles and runs it in VC++ Express 2010 without complaints.

I tried the same code in VC++ 2013 Community and it fails because it can't find a max template that takes (int, int).

I corrected the max function to take the arguments (T const& t1, T const& t2) instead and everything works.

My question is: is this version-specific or is there a compiler option or setting that allows you to pass literals as non-constant ref arguments?

The only way I could coerce the code to work otherwise is by adding a reference to `<algorithm>` which obviously calls another (correct) version of max. Her includes aren't shown in their entirety in the screen-recording so I guess she could have 'cheated' for the sake of simplicity since she hadn't bought up const& yet, but I would be surprised.

Comment: It's an evil MSVC extension.

Comment: It actually fails in MSVC 2013? I'm impressed.

Comment: It does. With default project settings and everything.

Comment: I could credit you for an answer if you added a bit more "meat" to your comment, @chris ;)

Comment: @chris Actually, I can get it to fail in MSVC2010. It's not the extension.

Comment: @T.C., That's good to hear. OP, for the references to temporaries in general, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-const lvalue references do not bind to rvalues (including all literals except string literals). This (properly) refuses to compile even in MSVC 2010:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
T max(T& t1, T& t2)
{
  return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "max of 33 and 44 is: " << ::max(33,44) << endl;
                                     //^^
    return 0;
}
```

The scope resolution operator `::` forces the compiler to attempt to use the `max` you defined in the global namespace.

In fact, the following code [compiles with GCC/libstdc++ and Clang/libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ffb4f7d80033c06) (at least the version on Coliru at the time of this writing):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
T max(T& t1, T& t2)
{
  return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "max of 33 and 44 is: " << max(33,44) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that `<iostream>` in those compilers/standard libraries (and MSVC 2010) also pulled in `std::max`, which ends up getting called due to the `using namespace std;`. MSVC 2013's `<iostream>` apparently *doesn't* pull in `std::max`, so you get an error.

There is an evil MSVC extension that allows non-const lvalue references to bind to rvalues, but that apparently doesn't cover primitive types like `int`.